# Robot can not avoid obstacle in navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, 2dcostmap, dwa-local-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ros-indigo on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am trying to use navigation stack, but I have some problem.
My robot can move "Initial Pose" to "goal", But can't avoid obstacles. Whether the obstacle require plugins (costmap_2d::StaticLayer) to be inserted in configuration file. Please can one suggest me asap.  Thank's in advanced.

My configuration files are as following:

1. common_costmap_params.yaml

   obstacle_range: 2.5
   raytrace_range: 3.0

   footprint: [[-0.20, -0.20], [-0.20, 0.20], [0.20, 0.20], [0.20, 0.20]]

   footprint_padding : 0.03
   inflation_radius: 0.30
   cost_scaling_factor: 1
   map_type: costmap

   max_obstacle_height: 1.0
   min_obstacle_height: 0.65

   transform_tolerance:  10.0

   obstacle_layer:
   observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
   laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: sensor, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true, observation_persistence: 0.0, expected_update_rate: 0.0, max_obstacle_height: 1.0, min_obstacle_height: 0.65, obstacle_range: 2.5, raytrace_range: 3.0, inf_is_valid: false}
2. global_costmap_params.yaml

   global_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_link
   update_frequency: 3.0 #20 3
   publish_frequency: 2.0 #20 2
   static_map: true

   rolling_window : true

   width: 10.0
   height: 10.0

   resolution: 0.1
3. local_costmap_params.yaml

   local_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_link
   update_frequency: 8.0 #10
   publish_frequency: 6.0 #10
   static_map: false
   rolling_window: true

   width: 4 #10.0
   height: 4 #10.0
   resolution: 0.01 #0.05
4. dwa_local_planner.yaml

   DWAPlannerROS:
   max_vel_x: 0.1099
   min_vel_x: -0.1099

   max_vel_y: 0.0
   min_vel_y: 0.0

   acc_lim_th: 0.01099
   acc_lim_x: 0.07999
   acc_lim_y: 0.0 #0.0

   max_trans_vel: 0.0999
   min_trans_vel: 0.0199

   max_rot_vel: 0.05099
   min_rot_vel: 0.01999
   rot_stopped_vel: 0.02

   sim_time:   1.7
   vx_samples: 10
   vy_samples: 1
   vtheta_samples: 40

   forward_point_distance: 0.0 # this value is being used as a cost value for robot alignment to the path
   holonomic_robot: false

   meter_scoring: true

   dwa: true

   yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
   xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
   latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true

   publish_cost_grid: true

   path_distance_bias:   32.0
   goal_distance_bias:  24.0
   occdist_scale:  0.1
   stop_time_buffer: 2.0
   oscillation_reset_dist: 0.1
   prune_plan: false
5. move_base_params.yaml

   shutdown_costmaps: false

   controller_frequency: 1.0
   controller_patience: 1.0

   planner_frequency: 1.0
   planner_patience: 1.0

   conservative_reset_dist: 0.2 #distance from an obstacle at which it will unstuck itself

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249205/robot-can-not--avoid-obstacle-in-navigation-stack/) by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-12-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-12-19**:
at what height is your sensor frame? If it is outside the limits `max_obstacle_height: 1.0, min_obstacle_height: 0.65`, it would not work.

**Comment by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on 2016-12-19**:
Hi Procopio, Thanks for comments.
My sensor frame height is at 0.71 meter.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-12-20**:
Do you see the obstacles in rviz?

**Comment by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on 2016-12-21**:
Yes I can see the obstacle in rviz.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-12-27**:
Do you see your costmaps in rqt dynamic reconfigure in move base?

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-01-06**:
This won't solve your problem, but there's a YAML bug in the global_costmap_params.yaml you posted: you forgot to indent the lines after "global_costmap:".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Sorry for late reply. I added following plugins in global_costmap_params.yaml and local_costmap_params.yaml which solved the problem.

plugins:

```
- {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"} 

- {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

---

Originally posted by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) with karma: 26 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ssj](https://answers.ros.org/users/31577/ssj/) on 2017-09-07**:
Thank you for your answer,I am facing same problem I added the above plugins but still no difference in robot behaviour, it still does not maintain distance from obstacle and then stuck in obstacles and cant move further.

**Comment by [P Govind Rao](https://answers.ros.org/users/65661/p-govind-rao/) on 2020-12-15**:
Sir i am also facing same problem i did what you did still my robot is not avoiding obstacles it's colliding sir please help me out i am going through a robotics competition